# zend framework 2 module: call function to populate a dropdownlist in the frontend

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework, module, zend-framework2

Hi im busy creating a module.

Now my problem is, i really want to understand how i would approach this problem.

1.I got a front-end that needs a dropdownlist that must be populated with data from a service function call to an api.

```
MyService.php

    public function myFunction() {
      return $call->get(/list/);
    }
```

Now how would i get the data as easy as possible to be used by others in the front-end when writing this Zend Framework 2 Module?

I would be happy to learn and be shown the right way.

Comment: Create a controller that passes back an repsonse wihin your format like a `JsonModel(['1' => 'item'])`? #overthinking? Your question is a bit broad so you might show some code of what you've already built or started on instead of just asking for advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using:
https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/modules/zend.form.view.helpers.html#formselect

```
$element = new Element\Select('language');
$element->setValueOptions(array(
    '0' => 'French',
    '1' => 'English',
    '2' => 'Japanese',
    '3' => 'Chinese'
));
echo $this->formSelect($element);`
```

this will generate a valid html selectbox, with the given options